# Iwahori subalgebra as maximal solvable

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

I think the following is true, but haven't came up with a proof myself. Thanks in advance!

Let $G$ be a semisimple (to avoid more words) algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$. Write $F=\mathbb{C}((t))$ and $\mathcal{O}=\mathbb{C}[[t]]$.
Is it true that a maximal solvable Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}(F)$ that is also a finitely generated $\mathcal{O}$-module must be an Iwahori subalgebra? In other words, is it true that all such Lie subalgebras are conjugate?

(feel free to replace $F$ by your favorite non-archimedean local field)

Comment: What does $\mathcal O$-finite mean? I would've thought of $\mathfrak b(F)$ and $\mathfrak b + t^{-1}\mathfrak g(\mathbb C[t^{-1}])$ as other maximal solvable subalgebras, not conjugate to Iwahoris or each other.

Comment: Pardon and thanks - by $\mathcal{O}$-finite I mean it's a finitely generated $\mathcal{O}$-module.